# EditText пересоздает ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

У меня есть ListView, в каждом ряду которого есть edittext. Если я кликну на editText в этом ряду, но появляется клавиатура. Но она, по какой-то причине, начинает пересоздаваться ([это видео поможет понять, о чем речь](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E7jBVvWG4vQqCRq92GvdMDfNGSmT1dEA/view). Я так понимаю, что при клике на EditText, он пересоздает обновляет Adapter. Я пробовал исправить это, добавив `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPin"` в манифест, но в этом случае возникает другая проблема - если editText находится в самом конце списка, то она попадает под клавиатуру. Как это исправить?

mainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

    </ExpandableListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/changeRowLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country_name_change"
        android:layout_width="168dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:text="Country name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/days_count_change"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/input"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:clickable="true"
        tools:text="666"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="116dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:text="666" />
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня было то же самое при динамическом добавлении в ExpandableList нового EditText, клава сходила с ума. Мне помог вызов requestFocus() для каждого EditText. Правильно ли так делать - понятия не имею)